# Hitting API call limits

Tags: rest-api

We are hitting our API usage limit for the last 2 days and we are getting `REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED`. We are not able to figure out what/which app is making all the calls. All our known apps don't even add up to 5% of the quota.

I can view the number of calls from a report but is there a way that I can get what is the source of the call? like an app or IP.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Developer Console also consumes API requests because it is based on the Tooling API.

The report "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days" will show Client Id column as blank for API requests consumed by developer console.

It might happen that the console is being used extensively in the org the last 2 days by system admins and/or developers.

If this is the case, consider moving to [VS Code IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/), which is compatible with scratch orgs, sandboxes, and DE orgs

Comment: thanks for the clue @shamina but we don't use the console in the production instance.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot were you able to find out the cause of API limit increase ?

Answer (score 0):

From the "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days" report, find the username consuming the most APIs and look at the Login History of that user.  That will tell you the IP address, the login type and the application.